# Url Encoded Javascript Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

So in Url Encoded Javascript (javascript:[js]), non-ASCII characters in the code (e.g. parenthesis and spaces in the jQuery selector) are being inadvertently encoded.

Any idea how I can go around this?

Normal:

`$('.panel-default:first div h3 table tbody tr td div ul li:last a').attr('onclick').replace("DELETECPRO", "MIGRATECACPRO");`

Url Encoded:

`%24%28%27.panel-default%3Afirst+div+h3+table+tbody+tr+td+div+ul+li%3Alast+a%27%29.attr%28%27onclick%27%29.replace%28%22DELETECPRO%22%2C+%22MIGRATECACPRO%22%29%3B`

Comment: you can try replacing `+` with `%20`, I guess, but what exactly is it you're doing?  how are you testing this string to determine that it won't work?

Comment: javascript:[x] Is used in chromes url tab and is used to basically put javascript into the console and run it. Im testing from the url directly. I will try the %20 now.

Comment: What are you using to insert said code into the url? copy paste? a bookmarklet? some javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
decodeURIComponent("%24%28%27.panel-default%3Afirst+div+h3+table+tbody+tr+td+div+ul+li%3Alast+a%27%29.attr%28%27onclick%27%29.replace%28%22DELETECPRO%22%2C+%22MIGRATECACPRO%22%29%3B")
.replace(/\+/g, " ")
```

Comment: All spaces used with javascript: in the url tab are changed to a + so the .replace wont work.

Comment: @JohnButler _"All spaces used with javascript: in the url tab are changed to a + so the .replace wont work"_ Not certain about requirement ? Format input string to remove "+" character ? At `js` at post `.replace()` chained to `decodeURICOmponent` having encoded input string as parameter  should return `"$('.panel-default:first div h3 table tbody tr td div ul li:last a').attr('onclick').replace("DELETECPRO", "MIGRATECACPRO");"` . Is expected response selector string , followed by `.replace()`

Comment: Basically im trying to get iMacros script to run some JS to change a onclick= bit of string from DELETECPRO() to MIGRATECACPRO() but its really hard to select it because theres no ID anywhere near it so I need to use this many selectors but the space between it stops it from working.